# Should go.sum file be checked in to the git repository?

Tags: go

I have a program with source code hosted on GitHub that uses Go Modules introduced in go 1.11.

`go.mod` file describes my dependencies, but `go.sum` file seems to be a lockfile. Should I be adding `go.sum` to my repository or should I gitignore it?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#releasing-modules-all-versions:

> Ensure your go.sum file is committed along with your go.mod file.

Comment: "See [FAQ below](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#should-i-commit-my-gosum-file-as-well-as-my-gomod-file) for more details and rationale."

Answer (score 138):

(Building on a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53852916/2350083).)

Yes, commit `go.sum`.

> Ensure your `go.sum` file is committed along with your `go.mod` file. See FAQ below for more details and rationale.

From the [FAQ](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#should-i-commit-my-gosum-file-as-well-as-my-gomod-file):

> #### Should I commit my 'go.sum' file as well as my 'go.mod' file?
>
> Typically your module's `go.sum` file should be committed along with
> your `go.mod` file.
>
> - `go.sum` contains the expected cryptographic checksums of the content of specific module versions.
> - If someone clones your repository and downloads your dependencies using the go command, they will receive an error if there is any
>   mismatch between their downloaded copies of your dependencies and the
>   corresponding entries in your `go.sum`.
> - In addition, `go mod verify` checks that the on-disk cached copies of module downloads still match the entries in `go.sum`.
> - Note that `go.sum` is not a lock file as used in some alternative dependency management systems. (`go.mod` provides enough information
>   for reproducible builds).
> - See very brief [rationale here](https://twitter.com/FiloSottile/status/1029404663358087173) from
>   Filippo Valsorda on why you should check in your `go.sum`. See the
>   ["Module downloading and
>   verification"](https://tip.golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Module_downloading_and_verification)
>   section of the tip documentation for more details. See possible future
>   extensions being discussed for example in
>   [#24117](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24117) and
>   [#25530](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/25530).

Comment: This answer should be the selected as OP's answer. Because it is more complete.